# How to create unique ids in dynamic table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coldfusion

I'm trying to get unique id for each table row on my input fields and buttons. Currently all ids in my table are the same. I want to set unique id for each input field ans save button. Here is my HTML code:

```
<cfoutput query="qryTable" group="DateSch">
    <tbody> 
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="#StartTime#">#DateFormat(DateSch,'mm/dd/yyyy')#</td>
        </tr>
        <cfoutput>
            <tr>
                <td>#TimeFormat(StartTime,'hh:mm tt')#</td>
                <td>#TimeFormat(EndTime,'hh:mm tt')#</td>
                <td>
                    <label>
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="email" placeholder="example@gmail.com">
                        <input type="button" id="slot" name="slot" class="slot" value="Save" onClick="saveSlot('#TimeSlotID#')">
                    </label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </cfoutput>
    </tbody>
</cfoutput>
```

As you can see from code above my input field ids are all email and my button ids are slot. How I can make them unique for each row? If anyone can help please let me know.

Comment: How are the rows generated? It's at the generation stage that you set the unique ids using e.g. a simple counter - we'd need to see the code that creates the rows

Comment: I use ColdFusion to populate my table with info from DB.

Comment: `we'd need to see the code that creates the rows`

Comment: @user3023588 That's potentially going to make this a ColdFusion question. You could certainly create a bunch of IDs by javascript, but if ColdFusion is generating the table it's likely better to create the IDs as part of that.

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `currentRow` to the ID

```
<cfoutput query="qryTable" group="DateSch">
<tbody> 
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="#StartTime#">#DateFormat(DateSch,'mm/dd/yyyy')#</td>
    </tr>
    <cfoutput>
        <tr>
            <td>#TimeFormat(StartTime,'hh:mm tt')#</td>
            <td>#TimeFormat(EndTime,'hh:mm tt')#</td>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email#currentRow#" class="email" placeholder="example@gmail.com">
                    <input type="button" id="slot#currentRow#" name="slot" class="slot" value="Save" onClick="saveSlot('#TimeSlotID#')">
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </cfoutput>
</tbody>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Is that the best way to do that? I know for currentRow but I used that when I do insert usually. Thanks for help.

Comment: What are you inserting? Using currentRow is the most efficient way to do this.

Comment: I was just wondering, I have not done any inserting in this case but I remember in the past I used currentRow for inserting.

Comment: Whether or not this is the best way or not depends on what you are attempting to do.  If all you really need is to make the id's unique, this is the simplest way.  However, once you submit the form, all those fields named email may not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

- To dynamically add unique id to the row use [uniqueId](https://api.jqueryui.com/uniqueId/) or just a counter with some specific prefix.
- To make `input` ids unique add entity id or the row number to them.

Answer (score 0):

There is another thread here:
[Create GUID / UUID in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript)

If you cannot find a solution there:
I got a UUID class from Erik Giberti (AF-Design). While his file is no longer available for downloading, I would be willing to provide it to.

Comment: You gave your question the label "Javascript". Are you sure you need a javascript solution? Or can the unique ids be generated where your code is generated?